no such table: BOOKS (SELECT * FROM BOOKS)
I have tried many time; the searched data are all about
db.execute there is no data about db.query, in this case I cannot select data from database and also showing null value in calling.
I think everything is ok.
DatabaseHelper.dart
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'models/book.dart';

class DatabaseHelper {
  DatabaseHelper._privateConstructor();

  static final DatabaseHelper instance = DatabaseHelper._privateConstructor();

  static Database? _database;

  Future<Database> get database async => _database ??= await _initDatabase();

  Future<Database> _initDatabase() async {
    Directory documentDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

    String path = join(documentDirectory.path, 'asset/database/saheeh_bukhari.db');

    return await openDatabase(path);
  }

  Future<List<Book>> getBooks() async {
    Database db = await instance.database;

    var books = await db.query('books');

    print(books);

    List<Book> bookList = books.isNotEmpty
    ? books.map((e) => Book.fromMap(e)).toList()
        : [];

    return bookList;
  }
}

Home.dart
body: Center(
        child: FutureBuilder<List<Book>>(
          future: DatabaseHelper.instance.getBooks(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Book>> snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return Center(
                child: Text("Loading..."),
              );
            }
            return snapshot.data!.isEmpty
                ? Center(
                    child: Text("No data found."),
                  )
                : ListView(
                    children: snapshot.data!.map((book) {
                      return Center(
                        child: ListTile(
                          title: Text(book.dari),
                        ),
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                  );
          },
        ),
      ),

I have tried many time; the searched data are all about db.execute there is no data about db.query, in this case I cannot select data from database and also showing null value in calling.

I don't understand your question, the error message is quite clear you're trying to query a Table named "books" in your sqlite database. There's no table named like that in your database so it doesn't work. You need to create the Table first.

The table is already exist in database but I cannot access it. The matter is how to access this table?

And the path of database is 100% correct.

Without seeing the database It's hard to say, the error message is usually correct, you should check that you are loading the correct database and that you typed the name of the table correctly "books" VS "book" for exemple are completely different.

Is there data rows in your table?
